# Checking toggle state of multiple buttons after toggling any of the buttons

Tags: jquery, button, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I am using bootstrap and jQuery to control a set of toggle buttons, and the after affect of pressing those buttons. The HTML button toggling is controlled by data-toggle="button":

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" style="margin-left:5px">
    <button id="fullWidth" class="btn btn-toggle" data-toggle="button">full</button>
    <button id="halfWidth" class="btn btn-toggle" data-toggle="button">half</button>
</div>
<button id="flight" class="btn btn-toggle" data-toggle="button">Flight</button>
<button id="derived" class="btn btn-toggle" data-toggle="button">Derived</button>
```

and my js segment (which at the bottom of the web page body at the mo.) is as follows:

```
        $('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
        if (($('#derived').hasClass('active')) && ($("#flight").hasClass('active'))){
            DO SOME STUFF
        }
        else if ($("#derived").hasClass('active')){
            DO SOME STUFF               
            if ($("#halfWidth").hasClass('active')){
            DO SOME STUFF               
            }
            else {
            DO SOME STUFF               
            }
        }
        else if ($("#flight").hasClass('active')){
            DO SOME STUFF               
            if ($("#halfWidth").hasClass('active')){
            DO SOME STUFF
            }
            else {
            DO SOME STUFF
            }
        }
        else {
        DO SOME STUFF
        }
    });
```

My problem is, the JS checks the state of the toggle buttons *before* the toggle change. I want to be able to select the option to change first, and then have the js run it's checks after after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap toggle button is just a regular button that changes its CSS class when clicked.  Unfortunately the callback for your ‘onclick’ runs before bootstrap gets called to change the class.  You can just make your own bootstrap ‘custom-toggle-btn’ extending a regular ‘btn’ and then manually toggle the ‘active’ class as the first line in your onclick function.
Something like this:

```
$('.custom-btn-toggle').click(function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('active'); // Add this line – note the change in class-name above

    if (($('#derived').hasClass('active')) && ($("#flight").hasClass('active'))){
        DO SOME STUFF
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. Note to others: remove `data-toggle="button"` when doing this or you get a double toggle. Not sure where class `btn-toggle` came from, I just use `type="button" class="btn"` and then select by id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `active` class instead of defining a custom button. You'll have to use both the jQuery [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) functions. First, add a separate class (e.g., `checked`) to the and then in the `click` callback put the following:

```
callback = function() {
  $(.btn-toggle).toggleClass('checked');
  $(.btn-toggle).hasClass('checked');
  // do your checks and other stuff
}

$(.btn-toggle).click(callback);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using .toggle() function of jQuery instead of .click() function.

You can search in [The jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and see what you need!

Comment: From what I read, this toggles the css of the element itself and doesn't report on the state of an element after it has been clicked. Please provide a code example if you know how to make `.toggle()` work as the OP described.